# Web application / program design architecture

Tags: c#, web-applications, architecture

we are planning to upgrade our web site and use the N-TIER design. i have read 
[this article](http://apparch.codeplex.com/releases/view/19802) which is quite good in my opinion.
**My questions are:**
1) is this architecture still valid for designing an application ?
2) should we use  other architecture like the onion , 3 layer , ddd and so on?
3) in the Service Layers the article suggest that we divide the data messages and the commands, is the best implementation is to create two services one for data and one for commands ?
Thanks

Comment: You really cant expect us to read 150 pages to answer your question. Perhaps reword your question, pointing to specific areas of architecture that you want advice on, rather than "is this still valid". A lot of architecture (especially DDD) is preferential and thus would be an subjective answer.

Comment: Not a real question. Please close

Comment: @ RPM1984 - I don't expect anyone to read a 150 page article (unless he wants to) to answer my questions, if he knows it or the suggested architecture and have an incite on the matter it would be nice. some times the manner of the question is more important than the question it self. thank you for you answer about `DDD` i will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture depends on what kind of project you need to create, complexity of project and business logic, scalability, maintainability, any way you should implement your project in the way that you can easily change your code and the tiers and classes should be much more
decoupled you should use ASP.NET MVC for application layer, and I suggest to use IoC-contaners for dependency injection, you can start with 3 layer architecture with
Repositories data access layer, Services classes business logic layer, ASP.NET MVC application layer
and another thing you should use ORM like Nhibernate or Entity Framework
If you have a complex domain you should look at the DDD

Comment: please explain if you can, what have you meant by "Complex domain" - ?

Comment: I mean that if you have a complex business logic and big domain look at DDD. Is your project is business application?

Comment: yes it is, its fully b2b portal.

Comment: if don't have much experience 3 - layer classic architecture better for you

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes this article is still a good article
2. This really depends on
   your technical and functional
   requirements. You can not start with
   an architecture and assume the
   implementation will fit any
   application.
3. see 2

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the applications requirements.

I tend to prefer the 4 tier design in that i have:

1. Data access
2. Entities
3. Facades
4. UI

However i have worked with developers who prefer to use pure business objects. That is the objects themselves arent truely representations of the records in the data store and they themselves contain all functionality necessary to perform the actions they need to perform. This includes data access. One example of this is approach is [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Default.aspx#).

I do feel this discussion is a bottomless pit of opinions based on upon experience though :)

Comment: This discussion are the essence of computer science in my opinion, and i love them :).  thanks